# Why does Spark Cassandra Connector fail with NoHostAvailableException?

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I am having problems getting Spark Cassandra Connector working in Scala.

I'm using these versions:

- Scala 2.10.4
- spark-core 1.0.2
- cassandra-thrift 2.1.0 (my installed cassandra is v2.1.0)
- cassandra-clientutil 2.1.0
- cassandra-driver-core 2.0.4 (recommended for connector?)
- spark-cassandra-connector 1.0.0

I can connect and talk to Cassandra (w/o spark) and I can talk to Spark (w/o Cassandra) but the connector gives me:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /10.0.0.194:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/10.0.0.194:9042] Cannot connect))

What am I missing? Cassandra is a default install (port 9042 for cql according to cassandra.yaml). I'm trying to connect locally ("local").

My code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext("local","test",conf)
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("myks","users")
val rr = rdd.first
println(s"Result: $rr")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local in this context is specifying the Spark master (telling it to run in local mode) and not the Cassandra connection host.

To set the Cassandra Connection host you have to set a different property in the Spark Config

```
import org.apache.spark._

val conf = new SparkConf(true)
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "IP Cassandra Is Listening On")
        .set("spark.cassandra.username", "cassandra") //Optional            
        .set("spark.cassandra.password", "cassandra") //Optional

val sc = new SparkContext("spark://Spark Master IP:7077", "test", conf)
```

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md